# Interpretation of Nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I use Mathematica to obtain the nullspace of a matrix. My impression is that the sign of the nullspace does matter, that is to say, if a matrix has a nullspace of:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}  -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{array} \right) $$

then, I can also assume that nullspace as well equals to:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}  1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ \end{array} \right) $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Null space is not a single vector. It is a subspace.

Comment: Then, is my assumption correct? Sorry, my linear algebra is rather rusty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NullSpace` command provides a basis of the nullspace of the matrix. And if a set $B=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of some vector space, then so is any set of the form $\{\pm v_1,\pm v_2,\ldots,\pm v_n\}$. So, the answer to your question is affirmative.